# What chat rooms are available to users?

Tags: discussion, chat

A recent meta discussion made me interested in seeing what chat rooms were available. I remember seeing a few rooms, but not being interested in having discussions in those rooms. Now, I can't seem to find any of those rooms.

How do I access a chat room through the UI?

---

https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=salesforce.stackexchange.com

This is a link to the active rooms, which are mostly discussions generated from the auto-chat link. Have tag based chat rooms or discussion rooms been tried in the past on SF.SE?

Comment: Dummy text so I can type [chat] and get a link

Comment: It seems that open office hours has been frozen due to inactivity -- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53431/open-office-hours

Comment: Wow, only a 15 day period before the room gets closed? Feels kind of short.. I'd have expected a month or so. I can see 15 days on Se, but not on the other stacks, were pretty low-activity.

Comment: Is there any way that the room can get reopened? Probably worth us trying to keep making occasional posts in it if it does just to keep it alive.

Comment: Looks like its frozen, but you can still join & chat in it. Only a mod can unfreeze it, but judging from the low feedback to this meta post compared to others I don't think we'll see much activity even if it was unfrozen. I'd rather the room be set to never freeze, so theres a "catch-all" room, but I'm not sure if this is possible. Between how hidden chat is (only link I can find is under the site switcher) I'd expect low use anyway..

Comment: Anyone should be able to join, and posting there should unfreeze. That's my understanding, anyway.

Comment: I actually cant comment.. looks like you posting in the room didn't unfreeze it, and seems like other users cant comment to unfreeze it. I think theres an explicit action that needs to be taken to unfreeze a room under the room options. [Reference on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70198/how-do-i-unfreeze-a-frozen-chat-room)

Comment: I think having a room for new users to ask questions or to have light discussions could be useful, but the rooms are low visibility & prone to freezing, which kind of reduces their usefulness here ..

Comment: @AdrianLarson I cam here for the same purpose :) unfortunately your posts did not unfreeze it :(

Comment: When the site was in beta, the chat room link was prominently displayed and it got a lot more use as a consequence. Now, the link itself is difficult to even find. Out of sight, out of mind is how I tend to think of it. That's greatly contributed to its demise IMO.